# How to draw a simple LSTM network

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, matlab

I'm new to deep learning, I am learning LSTM for my PhD work. This is a simple LSTM network for sequence classification.
This code is from MATLAB tutorial:

`layers = [sequenceInputLayer(1)
    lstmLayer(5,'OutputMode','last')
    fullyConnectedLayer(3)
    softmaxLayer
    classificationLayer];`

For simplicity, the dimension of the input sequence is `1`, there are `3` classes.

I am trying to draw the diagram of this network. This is my attempt:
[image]

Is this right? Should the LSTM blue units be connected? The orange units are the softmax layer, is there any symbol the should be on each unit (like ∑)? The same question for each layer? Should be any extra layer to represent the "`classificationLayer`"? The `fullyConnectedLayer` is represented implicitly in the full connection in the last layer, Do I need to add any extra layer for this? Any other comments, please?

Comment: Chris Olah has some excellent LSTM diagrams here: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: That's right, I passed by this link before. But, it only illustrates the LSTM 'unit' diagram. I need to illustrate the whole layer and the whole network.

Comment: Were you able to find something?  It's kind of crazy how hard this is to find.

Comment: Actually, I did not reach anything. So, I had to improvise. I made some simple scetch and put it in a paper. The paper was accepted and it is not published in an impacted journal.
You can find it here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8760508/
Sorry, this site does not allow attaching figures to comments.

Answer (score 1):

When thinking of rnn/lstm/gru layer keep few points in mind.

1. **What is your inputs size?** In this case we have 5 word sentence so 5 input circle going into lstm layer with that every word value will be multiple by same weight value.
2. **How many lstm cell will be present inside lstm layer?** To keep it simple as we have 5 words we are keeping 5 lstm cell for each word then carry forwarding it's memory into next lstm cell.
3. **How many output categories we have?** The last lstm cell will be connected to the all 3 dense layer neurons and at each of the neurons softmax operation will happend just like normal fully connected neural network dense layer works.

[image: Based on the network description lstm network]